# Search .netrc file in bash, and return username for given machine

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I need a way *(the most portable)* in bash, to perform a search of the `~/.netrc` file, for a particular `machine api.mydomain.com` and then on the next line, pull the username value.

The format is:

```
machine a.mydomain.com
  username foo
  passsword bar
machine api.mydomain.com
  username boo
  password far
machine b.mydomain.com
  username doo
  password car
```

So, it should matchin `api.mydomain.com` and return exactly `boo` from this example.

```
awk '/api.mydomain.com/{getline; print}' ~/.netrc
```

Get's me the line I want, but how do I find the username value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ awk '/api.mydomain.com/{getline; print $2}' ~/.netrc
boo
```

To capture it in a variable:

```
$ name=$(awk '/api.mydomain.com/{getline; print $2}' ~/.netrc)
$ echo "$name"
boo
```

By default, awk splits records (lines) into *fields* based on whitespace.  Thus, on the line `username boo`, `username` is assigned to field 1, denoted `$1`, and `boo` is assigned to field 2, denoted `$2`.

Comment: nice, but `.netrc` allows to use one-line format `machine a.mydomain.com username foo  passsword bar`

Comment: @rysson In general, you are right: it is possible to put a complete entry on one line and this code, as you point out, would not work for that.  For this question, however, the OP was very specific about the format he was using: *"...and then on the next line, pull the username value."* I was answering his question as asked.

Answer (score 2):

If you like to avoid using the `getline` fuction use this:

```
awk '/api.mydomain.com/ {f=NR} f&&f+1==NR {print $2}' ~/.netrc
boo
```

As Ed write here: avoid using it.
http://awk.info/?tip/getline

This will find the line number of the pattern, and then
when line number is one more, print field `#2`

Can be shorten some to:

```
awk '/api.mydomain.com/ {f=NR} f&&f+1==NR&&$0=$2' ~/.netrc
```

or

```
awk 'f&&!--f&&$0=$2; /api.mydomain.com/ {f=1}' ~/.netrc
```

---

This may be the most robust way to do it.
If there are comments line or blank line after domain, other solution fails.

```
awk '/api.mydomain.com/ {f=1} f && /username/ {print $2;f=0}' ~/.netrc
boo
```

If domain is found, set flag `f`.  If flag `f` is true and next line has `username` print field `#2`

Answer (score 1):

This sed is as portable as I can make it:

```
sed -n '
    /machine[   ]\{1,\}api.mydomain.com/ {      
        # we have matched the machine
        :a
        # next line
        n
        # print username, if matched
        s/^[    ]\{1,\}username[        ]\{1,\}//p
        # goto b if matched
        tb
        # else goto a
        ba
        :b
        q
    }
' ~/.netrc
```

The whitespace in the brackets is a space and a tab character.

---

Looking at this with fresh eyes, this is what I would write now:

```
awk -v machine=api.mydomain.com '
    $1 == "machine" {
        if (m)
            # we have already seen the requested domain but did not find a username
            exit 1
        if ($2 == machine) m=1
    }
    m && $1 == "username" {print $2; exit}
' ~/.netrc
```

or if you like unreadable oneliners

```
awk '$1=="machine"{if(m)exit 1;if($2==M)m=1} m&&$1=="username"{print $2;exit}' M=api.mydomain.com ~/.netrc
```

Comment: This is the only answer so far that will handle a file where the username line comes after the password line. But it won't gracefully handle a machine match with no username and password: it will fall through to the next username line.

Comment: Good point. Before looking for "username" I should be looking for "machine" and if found then quit.

Answer (score 1):

This vanilla Bourne shell (which includes Bash, KSH, and more) function should parse any valid .netrc file: it handled everything I could think of. Invoke with `netrc-fetch MACHINE [FIELD]`. For your question, it would be `netrc-fetch api.mydomain.com user`.

```
netrc-fetch () {
  cat $HOME/.netrc | awk -v host=$1 -v field=${2:-password} '
    {
      for (i=1; i <= NF; i += 2) {
        j=i+1;
        if ($i == "machine") {
          found = ($j == host);
        } else if (found && ($i == field)) {
          print $j;
          exit;
        }
      }
    }
  '
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently stumbled upon this issue and couldn't find an answer which covers the one-line format (i.e. machine x login y password z), and inline or intra-line comments.

What I ended up with is making the file into one line with xargs (so only single spaces remain), then using grep with lookbehind (for the keyword) and lookahead (for the next whitespace or end of line)

```
xargs < ~/.netrc | grep -oP '(?<=machine api\.domain\.com ).*?(?=( machine)|$)' | grep -oP '(?<=login ).*?(?=\s|$)'
```

This could be of course developed into a function of sorts with extending the dots in the remote host variable with backslashes, printing the password as well, etc.

```
get_netrc_entry() {
    machine_entry=$(xargs < ~/.netrc | grep -oP "(?<=machine ${1//./\\.} ).*?(?=( machine)|$)")
    grep -oP '(?<=login ).*?(?=\s|$)' <<<"${machine_entry}"
    grep -oP '(?<=password ).*?(?=\s|$)' <<<"${machine_entry}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you could do:

```
 awk '/api.mydomain.com/{getline;print $2}' ~/.netrc ##$2 will print username
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to get user of password:

```
grep -A2 armdocker.rnd.ericsson.se ~/.config/artifactory.netrc | awk '/login/ {print $2}'
```

`grep -A2` gives back the following 2 lines of a requested machine